# Inverse htmlentities / html_entity_decode

Tags: php, string, html-entities, html-encode

Basically I want to turn a string like this:

`<code> &lt;div&gt; blabla &lt;/div&gt; </code>`

into this:

`&lt;code&gt; <div> blabla </div> &lt;/code&gt;`

How can I do it?

---

**The use case (bc some people were curious):**

A page like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) with a list of allowed HTML tags and examples. For example, `<code>` is a allowed tag, and this would be the sample:

```
<code>&lt;?php echo "Hello World!"; ?&gt;</code>
```

I wanted a reverse function because there are many such tags with samples that I store them all into a array which I iterate in one loop, instead of handling each one individually...

Comment: Will the source string always be in the same format: an HTML entity-encoded string wrapped in `<code>` tags?  Or do you require a solution that can handle more generic situations, where encoded and non-encoded characters may be mixed?

Comment: Interesting indeed. Could you provide a use case? Just curious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My version using regular expressions:

```
$string = '<code> &lt;div&gt; blabla &lt;/div&gt; </code>';
$new_string = preg_replace(
    '/(.*?)(<.*?>|$)/se', 
    'html_entity_decode("$1").htmlentities("$2")', 
    $string
);
```

It tries to match every **tag** and **textnode** and then apply **htmlentities** and **html_entity_decode** respectively.

Comment: thank you. I don't know which method should I go with, yours or adlawson's :)

Comment: @Alex You are welcome! Both methods has its own side effects. You need to test which works the best in your case.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't an existing function, but have a look at this.
So far I've only tested it on your example, but this function should work on **all** htmlentities

```
function html_entity_invert($string) {
    $matches = $store = array();
    preg_match_all('/(&(#?\w){2,6};)/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($matches as $i => $match) {
        $key = '__STORED_ENTITY_' . $i . '__';
        $store[$key] = html_entity_decode($match[0]);
        $string = str_replace($match[0], $key, $string);
    }

    return str_replace(array_keys($store), $store, htmlentities($string));
}
```

#### Update:

- Thanks to [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340355/mike) for taking the time to test my function with other strings. I've updated my regex from `/(\&(.+)\;)/` to `/(\&([^\&\;]+)\;)/` which should take care of the issue he raised.
- I've also added `{2,6}` to limit the length of each match to reduce the possibility of false positives.
- Changed regex from `/(\&([^\&\;]+){2,6}\;)/` to `/(&([^&;]+){2,6};)/` to remove unnecessary excaping.
- Whooa, brainwave! Changed the regex from `/(&([^&;]+){2,6};)/` to `/(&(#?\w){2,6};)/` to reduce probability of false positives *even further*!

Comment: adlawson++ That is a really neat solution.

Comment: You can do the same inversion in one step using very similar code to mine.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would achieve the same result. The closest I've come is using `return preg_replace('/(&(#?\w){2,6};)([^&;]*)/', html_entity_decode("$1") . htmlentities("$2"), $string);`, but it doesn't work. It's much more simple to tackle each problem separately than with a single regex.

Comment: @adlawson Why do you think regex is much more difficult? By the way you use regex too :) The common problem about regex is readability. But in this case regex is short and even faster. For instance all your code can be rewritten as this: `return preg_replace('/(.*?)(&(#?\w){2,6};|$)/se', 'htmlentities("$1").html_entity_decode("$2")', $string);`

Comment: By the way `&(#?\w){2,6};` is not very good for matching html entity because it will match `&ab#cd;`, but it will not match `&thetasym;`. I think `&#?\w+;` or something similar would be better.

Comment: I didn't say regex was more difficult, simply that it's much easier to tackle one part of the problem at a time, whether that's done with regex or not. I've just tested your regex and it does indeed work +1.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing alone will not be good enough for you. Whether it be regular expressions or simple string replacing, because if you replace the &lt &gt signs then the < and > signs or vice versa you will end up with one encoding/decoding (all &lt and &gt or all < and > signs).

So if you want to do this, you will have to parse out one set (I chose to replace with a place holder) do a replace then put them back in and do another replace.

```
$str = "<code> &lt;div&gt; blabla &lt;/div&gt; </code>";
$search = array("&lt;","&gt;",);

//place holder for &lt; and &gt;
$replace = array("[","]");

//first replace to sub out &lt; and &gt; for [ and ] respectively
$str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);

//second replace to get rid of original < and >
$search = array("<",">");
$replace = array("&lt;","&gt;",);
$str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);

//third replace to turn [ and ] into < and >
$search = array("[","]");
$replace = array("<",">");

$str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: I was hoping there's a built in function, or at least less code necessary to accomplish this. I don't like the idea of handling the conversion for each character...

Comment: If there is a built-in function, I do not know what it is. You could just make this a function, and call it whenever you need it with the string as a parameter. It really isn't that much code, and all of the operations would be quick. I think your desire is a little to specific for a built-in function, but then that is the point of user defined functions.

Comment: There would not be a built-in function for this because, as interesting as the question is, I can't see any use case here that isn't either a complete edge case, theoretical, or a horrid code smell.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have a small sollution, why not break html tags into an array and then compare and change if needed?

```
function invertHTML($str) {
    $res = array();
    for ($i=0, $j=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) { 
        if ($str{$i} == "<") { 
           if (isset($res[$j]) && strlen($res[$j]) > 0){
                $j++; 
                $res[$j] = '';
           } else {
               $res[$j] = '';
           }
           $pos = strpos($str, ">", $i); 
           $res[$j] .= substr($str, $i, $pos - $i+1); 
           $i += ($pos - $i); 
           $j++;
           $res[$j] = '';
           continue; 
        } 
        $res[$j] .= $str{$i}; 
    } 

    $newString = '';
    foreach($res as $html){
        $change = html_entity_decode($html);
        if($change != $html){
            $newString .= $change;
        } else {
            $newString .= htmlentities($html);
        }
    }
    return $newString; 
}
```

Modified .... with no errors.

Comment: The first `for` loop iterates over every character in the string individually and out of context. This will break for strings like `<div>5 > 1</div>`. Also, its best to pass `strlen($string)` by reference, otherwise it recalculates the length for every iteration.

Comment: I've just tested it with the OP's string, and with "5 > 1", and you get `Undefined offset: $i` in both cases.

Comment: Modified, no errors, althrough .... if you test a string 10k large you will get a 2.3 times faster result from my script than with your ``preg_match``.

Comment: While your function may perform slightly faster, mine has the advantage of inverting *any* html entity (&raquo;, &mdash, &heart etc). It was the strlen in `for ($i=0, $j=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {` that I meant should be passed by reference.

Comment: are you sure my example doesen't convert any html entity?

Comment: How can it if you explode around `<` `>` tags rather than the other way around.

Comment: give me one example with something that your script does much more than mine.

Comment: @adlawson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1551/discussion-between-mihai-iorga-and-adlawson)

Comment: ok, @adlawson has a point ... his script is slightly much slower but it's safer ...

Answer (score 1):

So, although other people on here have recommended regular expressions, which may be the absolute right way to go ... I wanted to post this, as it is sufficient for the question you asked.

Assuming that you are always using html'esque code:

```
 $str = '<code> &lt;div&gt; blabla &lt;/div&gt; </code>';
 xml_parse_into_struct(xml_parser_create(), $str, $nodes);
 $xmlArr = array();
 foreach($nodes as $node) { 
     echo htmlentities('<' . $node['tag'] . '>') . html_entity_decode($node['value']) . htmlentities('</' . $node['tag'] . '>');
 }
```

Gives me the following output:

```
&lt;CODE&gt; <div> blabla </div> &lt;/CODE&gt;
```

Fairly certain that this wouldn't support going backwards again .. as other solutions posted, would, in the sense of:

```
 $orig = '<code> &lt;div&gt; blabla &lt;/div&gt; </code>';
 $modified = '&lt;CODE&gt; <div> blabla </div> &lt;/CODE&gt;';
 $modifiedAgain = '<code> &lt;div&gt; blabla &lt;/div&gt; </code>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It appears that I haven't fully answered your question. There is no built-in PHP function to do what you want, but you can do find and replace with regular expressions or even simple expressions: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: What makes you think `print` will decode the entities? Also, this doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: @Matt OP could also use html_entity_decode. See edit for your second remark.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using buffers at all. `$var` is the same as `$out` in your example.

Comment: Didn't think it would be. Editing to remove false info.

Comment: This doesn't even come close to answering anything like the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a regular expression, e.g. preg_replace():

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php
- http://davebrooks.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/php-preg_replace-some-useful-regular-expressions/

Comment: Vomiting "REGULAR EXPRESSION!" and chucking arbitrary links on regular expressions at everybody is _not an answer_.